# Firebase Firestore geopoint range issue: Must be between -180 and 180

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, geopoints

i'm using firebase firestore database and trying to insert geopoint of any place in india
the problem is while inserting the longitude console gives red warning: Must be between -180 and 180
[image]

Comment: As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude, "Longitude is given as an angular measurement ranging from 0° at the Prime Meridian to +180° eastward and −180° westward." It's not clear why you expect -282 to be a valid value.

Comment: Given https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/78th_meridian_east, I suspect you want a longitude of  about 77.5.

Comment: i visited websites(https://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/) to get latitude and longitude of a point from map and tried fetching a geopoint in india and got the longitudes which are in -200 to -300

Comment: Hmm... I just searched for "Delhi" on that site and it gave me a longitude of 77.1... but basically, try adding 360 to all the longitudes you've received.

Comment: yes got it, now working fine, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation the [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint) requires:

> Latitude values in the range of [-90, 90]. Longitude values in the range of [-180, 180].

Which according to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) entry matches the values:

> Longitude is given as an angular measurement ranging from 0° at the Prime Meridian to +180° eastward and −180° westward.

With that said the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types) actually suggests to avoid this type and go for separate numeric fields due to limitations on queries, and suggests [Geo queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) for simple distance-based apps.